# Debugging Remote Java Application In STS 3.5.1

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-tool-suite

I looked here for the answer of my question but didn't get it, so asking following question.

From STS-3.5.1, I like to debug "Remote Java Application" deployed in WAS-8.0.

I know that in Eclipse we can create "Debug Configuration->Remote Java Application" to do the said debugging.

But STS-3.5.1->Debug Configuration, doesn't show "Remote Java Application" option.

Is this a known bug in STS-3.5.1, that it doesn't allow "Remote Debugging" of java applications  ?